# Erro permissão php ao fazer upload

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer upload de meus arquivos para o servidor lampp porem não tenho conseguido, o que pode está ocorrendo ?

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../uploads/1579387143.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/C_Upload.php on line 41

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpLlJqTq' to '../uploads/1579387143.jpg' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria/admin/paginas/C_Upload.php on line 41
```

Meu codigo da pagina de upload é:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

    $file = $_FILES['img'];
    $numfile = count(array_filter($file['name']));

    $folder = '../uploads';

    $permite = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg');
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

    $msg = array();
    $errorMsg = array(
        1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
            2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
            3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
            4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo' 
    );
    if($numfile <= 0)
            echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
    else{
            for($i = 0; $i < $numfile; $i++){
                $name   = $file['name'][$i];
                $type   = $file['type'][$i];
                $size   = $file['size'][$i];
                $error  = $file['error'][$i];
                $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

                $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
                $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

                if($error != 0)
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
                else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
                else if($size > $maxSize)
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
                else{

                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome))
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Upload Realizado com Sucesso!";
                    else
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";

                }

                foreach($msg as $pop)
                    echo $pop.'<br>';
            }
        }

}
?>
```

Comment: já verificou se a pasta onde esta salvando tem permissão de escrita ? (chmod 777)

Comment: Vlw erro corrigido !

Comment: 777 não pode, de as permissões corretas

Comment: coloquei na resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu processo do php provavelmente não esta com permissão para escrever no diretório, vá na pasta onde deseja salvar os arquivos e execute os comandos abaixo.

> Para descobrir qual o usuário do seu webserver pode usar o comando whoami no php

```
<?php
    //Exemplo para descobrir o usuario_webserver
    echo shell_exec("whoami");
```

Feito isso chame o arquivo php que ele vai imprimir o usuario que esta executando o processo.

**Supondo** que a pasta seja /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria

> Aplicando permissões de escrita, para isso use os comandos abaixo

```
sudo chown seu_usuario_do_linux:usuario_webserver_retornado_pelo_codigo_exemplo_acima /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria -R
sudo chmod 775 /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/jrassessoria -R
```

> Geralmente o usuario do webserver vai ser httpd ou www-data, depende da distro linux que você usa.